# Does Cortana azure bot channel needs speech to text services?

Tags: azure, bots, cortana

I am developing an Azure bot, and I am intending to link it to Cortana channel. But not sure if that need the speech to text to be part of the services needed to create that bot. or Cortana client handles the communication between cortana and the bot with the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding via speech is completely under your control.  The entire Cortana experience can be driven via text entry on Windows 10 and mobile app.  However, your skill may not pass certification if published because of screen-less devices like the Invoke and best practice of responding with voice is triggered by voice.  You can pull DeviceInfo and fail gracefully if there is no display.

Comment: Thanks @Micromuncher, However, I was asking if I link to cortana. Do I need to purchase a speech to text services or that will be handled by cortana?

Comment: No, you don't need to purchase a TTS service as that is handled by Cortana.  If you build your bot on Azure you have the typical hosting fees for an app service or function and there are free tiers (that equates to slow and shared resources).

Comment: You're welcome. I have instructions on how to do this around minute 3 here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCgqZPbQBQk&t=180s

Comment: Thank you just watched your video. Cool I recognize you from another video I watched :)